# Django Loop .save() time issues

Tags: python, django

I have the following code and everything does what it supposed to, each loop can varies in the amount of time for it to run. I've narrowed it down to the `.save()` function as the query on average takes .008 seconds to run per iteration. The `.save()` takes anywhere from .008 seconds to 1.13 seconds.

When performing 113 iterations, 1.13 seconds starts to add up.

Any suggestions to speed this up? 
The table size is up to 45,000 lines of data.

```
for mega, company, family, bed, sretail in beds:
    matt = FloorTracker.objects.get(showroom_number=strNum,mattress=bed)
    matt.brand = company
    matt.family = family
    matt.company = mega
    matt.suggested_retail = sretail
    matt.on_floor = 0 if request.POST.get('cb_' + bed) == None else 1
    matt.in_comparison = 0 if request.POST.get('cb_' + bed + '_comparison') == None else 1
    matt.in_vzone = 0 if request.POST.get('cb_' + bed + '_vzone') == None else 1
    matt.size = "" if request.POST.get('sz_' + bed) == 'blank' or not request.POST.get('sz_' + bed) else request.POST.get('sz_' + bed)
    matt.underbed = "" if request.POST.get('ub_' + bed) == 'blank' or not request.POST.get('ub_' + bed) else request.POST.get('ub_' + bed)
    matt.lastupdate = str(timezone.now())
    t0 = time.time()
    matt.save()
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print('query 1:', matt.mattress, total)
```

Comment: I think its going to be hard to speed it up too much, you could perhaps spare some ticks by using `'cb_{}'.format(bed)` etc to stop string concatenation but that would be minimal, what does `beds` contain?

Comment: It would be hard to make this updates any faster. If it's possible, maybe delete all affected FloorTracker objects and than insert them back with bulk_create?

Comment: Is it a remote database, which could explain the variability?

Comment: I'm working on pythonanywhere.com using their database and web hosting solutions.

Comment: `beds` is a list of lists. `beds =  [
                    ['Sealy','SBR','SBR','SBR Parsons Firm',449.99],
                    ['Sealy','SF','GS','GS GLEN TERRACE LXF',2299.99],
                    ['Sealy','SF','GS','GS RIVER PLACE LXP',2699.99],
]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update instead of Fetch and Save

You are fetching an object and then updating it's fields and saving it back. That's two hits on the db. you can do it in one operation. Use [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update)

```
FloorTracker.objects.filter(showroom_number=strNum,mattress=bed).update(
     lastupdate = str(timezone.now(),suggested_retail = sretail ....)
```

This is faster than retrieve and save and it's safer! This is an atomic operation, with retrieve, edit save you risk another thread updating your database while you are doing the edit and that data will be clobbered.

### Use transcation

As also suggested in th other answer, wrap the whole thing in a transaction and commit at the end.  This will be much faster

### User database default

Instead of assigning values in your code for None and not found instances, use defaults. This will save a few operations and lead to a bit of speed.

### Avoid repeatedly getting the same object

you have multiple calls like this:

```
request.POST.get('ub_' + bed)
```

You can do it once and reuse the value

```
ub_bed = request.POST.get('ub_' + bed)
```

Saving here will be small.

### Treat request.POST as a dictionary

If you are confident that all the fields are populated (If you used a django form here instead of relying on raw post data, you could really be ) you can access request.POST items as

request.POST['cb_' + bed]

but performance improvement will be marginal

### index

Last but not least, create an index on `showroom_number, mattress` this could possibly lead to a big boost.

Comment: I just heard back from the server host - it seems they're having issues with their MYSQL server. It's good to know it isn't my code, but this was a good practice to help clean things up. Great learning experience. Thanks a million.

Comment: glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

Django's default is to run on autocommit mode, so if you're not doing it already (and I assume you would have mentionned it), [wrapping all your updates in one single transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) will certainly improve performances.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest speed up is to avoid making one of the queries on each loop iteration.

```
bed_list = [b[3] for b in beds]
track_qs = FloorTracker.objects.filter(showroom_number=strNum, mattress__in=bed_list)
trackers = {t.mattress: t for t in track_qs}

for mega, company, family, bed, sretail in beds:
    matt = trackers[bed]
    ...
```

The other way to go would be to accumulate updates required and do all of them at once instead of doing a lot of single item updates.

Answer (score 0):

Following some of the suggestions by e4c5, I've had some improvement but I still have variable times for each iteration. Most iterations now take .005 seconds but about a quarter of them still take 1.3 seconds (pretty reliably 1.31 or 1.32 seconds).

The timing is an issue because I'm getting timeout from my server host and this is failing on my users. I really need it to be reliably under 20 seconds. We're coming up about anywhere from 30 seconds to 90 seconds.

Here is the update I made to the code. I'm not sure I completely understand transaction.atomic yet even after reading up on it but I think this is right:

```
def saveData(request,strNum, brand):
    #List of beds to loop through
    import time
    from django.db import transaction
    beds = bedSelect(brand)
    t3 = time.time()
    store = storeList.objects.get(storenumber=strNum)
    with transaction.atomic():
        for mega, company, family, bed, sretail in beds:
            try:
                t0 = time.time()
                FloorTracker.objects.filter(showroom_number=strNum,mattress=bed).update(
                    user = store.user,
                    showroom_number = store,
                    brand = company,
                    family = family,
                    mattress = bed,
                    company = mega,
                    suggested_retail = sretail,
                    on_floor = 0 if request.POST.get('cb_' + bed) == None else 1,
                    in_comparison = 0 if request.POST.get('cb_' + bed + '_comparison') == None else 1,
                    in_vzone = 0 if request.POST.get('cb_' + bed + '_vzone') == None else 1,
                    size = "" if request.POST.get('sz_' + bed) == 'blank' or not request.POST.get('sz_' + bed) else request.POST.get('sz_' + bed),
                    underbed = "" if request.POST.get('ub_' + bed) == 'blank' or not request.POST.get('ub_' + bed) else request.POST.get('ub_' + bed),
                    lastupdate = str(timezone.now()))
                t1 = time.time()
                total = t1-t0
                print(total)
```

Comment: Use an async task queue to avoid timing out. You cannot guarantee updating 45+k records in less than 20 seconds.

Comment: in this example, it's only 113 records. I just heard back from the server host - it seems they're having issues with their MYSQL server. It's good to know it isn't my code, but this was a good practice to help clean things up. Great learning experience.